# How to access RequireJS modules from browser console?

Tags: requirejs

Without Require.js it is possible to call global objects in the browser console, e.g.

```
app
app.movies
```

When I wrap code in RequireJS modules, how can I access the data from the modules in the browser console? I would find this helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 require("app").movies
```

?